# Find and replace using sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed, replace

I am trying to create a one line find and replace using cat and sed to complete the task inside a shell script. Here is where I am at so far:

`myscript.sh` contains the following:

```
date=$(date '+%Y%m%d'01)
ydate=$(date -d yesterday '+%Y%m%d'01)

cat myfile.txt | sed -r -n 's/$ydate/$date/'
```

Here is what I am expecting: The variables of `$ydate` and `$date` are set to have the date in `yyyymmdd01` format, respectively. When the `myscript.sh` file runs, it uses `cat` to pipe the output of `myfile.txt` (`myfile.txt` contains yesterdays date in the format shown) to the `sed` command. `sed` then takes the `cat` output locates yesterdays date and replaces it with todays date in the correct format.

This is not working as required so far.

I have also tried using "" around the `sed` command, without the `-n` and I have tried specifying the file `myfile.txt` after the `sed` command. It still will not locate the string and replace it.

Can anyone offer me some help as to how I can get this to operate as intended?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
myscript.sh contents:

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /var/named

date=$(date '+%Y%m%d'01)
ydate=$(date -d yesterday '+%Y%m%d'01)


# This line creates the serial number of the file
cat myfile.rpz | sed  "s/$ydate/$date/" myfile.rpz

# This line opens the file at the end for easier editing
#nano +999999999 myfile.rpz

# This line restarts the named service, waits 5 seconds, then closes.
#service named restart
#sleep 5s
#exit
```

myfile.rpz contents:

```
$TTL 600
@            IN    SOA  dns1.mysite.com. root.localhost.  (
                      2020042101   ; serial
                      1h           ; refresh
                      30m          ; retry
                      1w           ; expiry
                      30m)         ; minimum
               IN     NS    localhost.

dns1.mysite.com    IN      A       172.16.1.18
dns2.mysite.com    IN      A       172.16.2.18

; Redirect this site to localhost to block
; List last consolidated on 12/11/2018

; DNS Blocks
*.mad   IN      CNAME   *.

beans.com       A       127.0.0.1 ; this is a test case

*.000webhostapp.com     A       127.0.0.1
*.00h5.com      A       127.0.0.1
*.00webhostapp.com      A       127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Remove `-n`, remove `-r`, use double quotes and it should work. Use `set -x` to debug your scripts.

Comment: @KamilCuk I tried as you suggested, It still did not locate the date and replace it. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: You need double quotes around the regex so that the variables are evaluated. You don't want `-n` and you don't need `-r`. I did a quick test and, assuming your `myfile.txt` has what you actually think it has and matches `$ydate` then it should work (leaving off the `-n` and using double quotes). So, please show your `myfile.txt` and what your `$ydate` value is in that exact case.

Comment: I will get both files and show them here.

Comment: Edit your question and put it there. Too had to read in comments. Update your script to the latest corrected version (double quotes, no `-n`, etc) to make sure we know what we're looking at here. Pull it all together. It's really hard to tell what you've run last and what the values are. You haven't shown what `$ydate` is to check whether it matches what's in `myfile.txt`. You can show small samples of a data file. You don't need to post the whole thing. Just essentials.

Comment: @lurker, thanks for the help. I have done as you suggested and added it to the post section, it is much easier to read. The output of the $ydate is 2020042101 as of today.

Comment: I just created a file `myfile.rpz` with the contents you showed and ran the `sed` command. It worked fine for me. What this indicates is that the `sed` command as 
 you show it now is working fine. If you're not getting the results you want, it's a different issue. Where are you sending the output from your script? Terminal? A file?

Comment: @lurker I am sending the file out to myfile.rpz. I have also tried to use sed to edit in place and I still get the same results. I just ran it again, still the same issue.

Comment: @lurker, I got it to work! After you cnfirmed that it should work, I copied the current config that is running over myfile.rpz to start fresh. After doing this, it worked! There must have been something in my test file that it didnt like. THANK YOU SO MUCH for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first command the text between single quotes are not changed:

```
cat myfile.txt | sed -r -n 's/$ydate/$date/'
```

Before moving on (using double quotes) I suggest to get rid of the `cat`:

```
sed -r -n 's/$ydate/$date/' myfile.txt
```

The next command is mixing 2 styles of input.

```
cat myfile.rpz | sed "s/$ydate/$date/" myfile.rpz
```

In this case the output of the `cat` is ignored, because `sed` already finds an input file in its parameters. This line should be

```
sed "s/$ydate/$date/" myfile.rpz
```